# I am using Rsync for syncing to folders with images. I would like to process the images while rsync runs....I have a java code to resize the images

Tags: linux, image, rsync

I am using Rsync for syncing to folders with images. I would like to resize the images while Rsync runs. I have a java code to process the images.

I want Rsync to process the image (it returns processed image) via java program before syncing the folders and store the processed image in the folder.

Comment: Good idea! If you'd like it you may do it. We have no objections. What is your question?

Comment: how do I do it ?  
I have java code to process the image but need help to link it with rsync.

Comment: Process all your images first and then sync your folders.